# IBM ToolsCenter Bootable Media Creator equivlent for HP Proliant server

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ibm

Is there any IBM ToolsCenter Bootable Media Creator equivlent for HP Proliant server? With IBM TC BMC I can choose which server i'm using, and it will create a bootable cd for these servers, containing the newest firmware (BIOS, RAID card, SAS disk firmware, etc) update, then I boot server with this cd, and the firmware is updated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [HP Service Pack for ProLiant (SPP)](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/index.html).

This combines the firmware and system updates into a bootable DVD. The server's components are automatically detected. This package also allows you to install the operating system-specific tools and agents.

Answer (score 0):

HP Smart Update Firmware DVD does the job.
It is able to load additional files from the USB stick.